# Magento: Display sub-category list

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm building a Magento store and want to be able to display a list of categories and have each category link to its own page.

I have a 'Brands' category with an ID of 42 and I want to display a list of the sub-categories and ensure that each one links to the designated URL key in the CMS.

Has anyone had experience of doing this with Magento?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're comfortable editing your theme, this code snippet will bring you a list of all sub-categories of the current category (from the session, so this should work anywhere in your theme). I typically use this in app/design/frontend/default/*theme_name*/template/catalog/category/view.phtml

```
<?php
$_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory(); 
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($_category->entity_id);
$helper     = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
?>

<ul>
    <?php foreach ($collection as $cat):?>
            <?php if($_category->getIsActive()):?>
                <?php 
                     $cur_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat->getId());
                     $_img = $cur_category->getImageUrl();  
                ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($cat);?>">
                         <img src="<?php echo $_img?>" title="<?php echo $cat->getName();?>"/>
                         <cite><?php echo $cat->getName();?></cite>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endif?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks wookie, this worked like a charm.

Just out of curiosity, I have seen a number of threads on the Magento forums that suggest using CMS static block to link to a separate PHP file to achieve this (http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/14527/P15/). To me it seems to be a bit OTT when we can easily add the code above into the view.phtml file. Are you aware of the reasons for their suggestions?

Comment: ya, I'm not sure why you'd want to do that. Part of the problem with magento is that it's so tough to do basic stuff in a custom theme that people end up creating really obtuse solutions rather than by using the resources that are readily accessible (but poorly documented).

Comment: This didn't work for 1.4, tough I understand this must had been posted in the time of 1.2 or 1.3.. the below extension posted by Sid Vel saved my day!

Answer (score 4):

If You want to Display top level categories and subcategories U can do Like This..

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
            </a>
            <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
            <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
            <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

For Displaying Top Level Categories and Current Categories SubCategories you can Do like ....

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
            </a>
            <?php if ($currentCategory && $currentCategory->getId() == $_category->getId()): ?>
                <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                    <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Works great, thank you! But the last `<?php endif; ?>` in each snippet wasn't properly indented and thus got kicked by the SO system. Also two ampersands got html-escaped. Fixed both issues. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This question requires a long answer. I will point you to the right places.

1) Best solution is to use the free extension. I haven't tried it, but it will suit the purpose. You will have to do some CSS to achieve the right look and feel.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/1562/magento-easy-catalog-images
Demo: http://extension01.templates-master.com/gb/electronics.html

2) I do not trust in modules as it might become difficult to upgrade if the vendor decided to stop supporting it. I have used the information from the following forum thread to create a vew sites. Have a look... Might not be straight forward. You might have to make some copies of core files to the local directory.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/3770/P30/

Hopefully this will be of help to you :)

Comment: Hey mate, I wish I could rat up your post 10 times the extension you referred to saved me countless of hours in developing it myself.

Just for the sake of others, that ext states it's for 1.3 but it works like a charm on 1.4.

Thanks mate SUPER THUMBS UP

Answer (score 1):

I made this little video on how I create custom category listing blocks with Magento.
I am sure there are better ways of achieving this or even something I could have done better, but it’s just my method. I only created this it in hopes that it helps explain somethings to some people out there.

[Magento Custom Category Listing Block](http://www.devinrolsen.com/magento-custom-category-listing-block/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

after looking at all the solutions on the magento site, i found that wookiehangover's solution above worked and took about 8 seconds to implement.

creates a UL that you can style. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After creating static block you can get any list of the subcategories by this script:

```
        $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(5);
        $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories();

        if (count($_subcategories) <= 0) { return; }

        $count = 0;

        foreach($_subcategories as $_category) {     
                                                      $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());

                                                      $ret->{"object_".$count} ->url  = $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category);
                                                      $ret->{"object_".$count} ->name = $_category->getName();
                                                      $ret->{"object_".$count} ->id =  $_category->getId(); 
                                                      $ret->{"object_".$count} ->image =   $category->getImageUrl();
                                                      $count++;
                                                   } 

        return $ret;                                          

        } 


$list = list_subcategories(5);

echo "<pre>"; print_r($list); echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

How about listing only the categories belonging to the current item. Not all the categories on the page.

But in a tree like view.

CATEGORIE - sub cat 1
CATEGORIE 2 - sub cat 1 - sub sub cat 1

BR Cveto