# Calling Models in Magento Templates

Tags: magento, templates, model-view-controller

I am currently working on integrating HTML cuts into Magento's template, however, I am just a little stumped on the structure of Magento itself. I want to list all of the categories inside a custom template in the 'navigation/left'.phtml file. The following accepted answer [Magento: Display sub-category list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820012/magento-display-sub-category-list) seems to do what I need to do, however,I don't feel comfortable in calling a model inside of a view files as in MVC, which the accepted answer has done.

Is there a better way of putting this in another section of Magento, or perhaps a custom block which extends the Block_Catalog_Product_List class would be a better way of retrieving the categories?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is to create a module with a helper inside it, that returns the data you need. Then in the template file call this:

```
$data = Mage::helper('myhelper')->getCategoryList();
//do your magic with $data
```

There is no point in overriding blocks unless there is no other solution.